# Audio is working, but the speaker test doesn't work

Tags: sound, ubuntu-minimal

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a minimal cd on a netbook (Asus 1001 PXD).
I've installed the `ubuntu-desktop` package using the `--no-install-recommends` option.

Everything works fine, except the "sound test" for headphones or analog speakers.

Clicking on the "test" buttons (front left and front right) I don't hear any sound.
Despite this, the audio is working properly.

I've checked the audio levels with alsamixer; I have also checked that the test sounds actually exist in `/usr/share/sounds/alsa`.

I tried an installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS made with the desktop-cd, and in this case the speaker test works properly.

I suppose, therefore, that the problem could depend on the lack of a package, but I have not identified which one.

Answer (score 33):

I've found the solution:

it is needed to install the `libcanberra-pulse` package, that is recommended for the `gnome-session-canberra` package, which is one of the packages on which depends `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: still relevent after I reinstalled sound packages (and apparently forgot to reinstall some) on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: The test always plays to S/PDIF even when HDMI is selected as output and system sounds are playing through HDMI. Ubuntu 20.04 with latest libcanberra-pulse installed.

Comment: @Maarten LOL, I concur, in 2022 :)

Comment: Was a solution to the reported problem on 23.10.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating to Ubuntu 20.04. and rebooted.

I solved using:

`sudo apt-get install -y libcanberra-pulse`