# Ubuntu 20.04, I can hear audio from other sources, but the "Test" option where you can click "Front Left" and "Front Right" do not work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

So, as per the title audio is working.    I occasionally I have to do the pulseaudio restart trick to get it working again, not sure why that is happening but it's not frequent and "pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload" followed by selecting my correct audio output has been a fix 100% of the time so not worried about that but what is really bugging me is not having the audio test working so I can get left and right channels correct when connecting different audio devices (part of what I do for work so it's done often).

I don't get any errors on the screen or in journalctl / dmesg, etc...  it just doens't play.

Now also at the bottom of the sound settings you can select "Alert Sound" of "default", "bark" "drip" "glass" or "sonar"... clicking those only makes a click/chirp sound... like when a CD skips or an MP3 has a problem in the audio stream...  won't actually play a recognizable sound.

I've been through the Ubuntu troubleshooting tips found here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure  and the problem isn't solved.

The crazy thing is I get sound, play youtube or VLC content, can adjust volume, can switch to headsets/bluetooth/HDMI outputs... same thing happens everywhere, just can't play the "test sounds".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Audio is working, but the speaker test doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208359/audio-is-working-but-the-speaker-test-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Possible clone of [Audio is working, but the speaker test doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208359/audio-is-working-but-the-speaker-test-doesnt-work)

I had the same problem and I solved it using:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libcanberra-pulse
```