# Audio output device missing + Test Audio broken after installing Microsoft Teams

Tags: sound, devices, microsoft-teams

After installing Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.26453 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04.3, my audio output device goes missing from the Sound menu of System Settings. I'm using a Schiit Fulla 3 DAC/Amp. I was able to bring back audio output by doing the following:

```bsh
sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudo
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
sudo apt install pavucontrol -y
sudo reboot
```

Then, running `pavucontrol`, I can go to the configuration tab and find the device, setting its Profile to "Analogue Stereo Duplex". Going to the Output Devices tab, I find the device and click the tick to "Set as fallback".

This solves the audio playback issue in most apps (including Teams). However, strangely, when I click the "Test" button under Ubuntu's Sound settings, neither the "Front Left" nor "Front Right" buttons give audio output.

I hope the process described here helps some people fix their audio, which is clearly the main issue, as even uninstalling Teams and rebooting the PC would not bring it it back! But it is a little strange/annoying that the audio test doesn't work -- any suggestions would be great.

Comment: @Community the problem is explicitly stated in the penultimate paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/209782/1133585

`sudo apt install libcanberra-pulse`

The package must have been uninstalled when I was going through the options I found online for getting sound back.